# How to validate a specific Date and Time format using Python

Tags: python, datetime, format

I am writing a program to validate portions of an XML file.  One of the points I would like to validate is a Date Time format.  I've read up on the forum about using `time.strptime()` but the examples weren't quite working for me and were a little over my expertise.  Anyone have any ideas how I could validate the following.  This is the format the date and time must be in.

```
2/26/2009 3:00 PM
```

I am sure there is something built-in and very easy but I can't find.  Many thanks if you've run by this before and have suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean validate the datetime? Do you want to ensure it is properly formatted, an actual date that makes sense (i.e. not 13/45/20000), fits some other criteria?  What do you want to do with the datetime data after "validation"?

Comment: My first goal was to make sure it was properly formatted.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, you can use [`datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
from datetime import datetime


def validate_date(d):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


print validate_date('2/26/2009 3:00 PM')  # prints True
print validate_date('2/26/2009 13:00 PM')  # prints false
print validate_date('2/26/2009')  # prints False
print validate_date("Should I use regex for validating dates in Python?")  # prints False
```

Comment: Great answer. Following typical [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) style, the simplest and most robust way to test whether you can FOO a BAR is usually to just FOO it and see if it works…

Comment: @abarnert thank you, asking for forgiveness is definitely easier!

Answer (score 3):

This is how you do it:

```
    from datetime import datetime

    def validate(datetime_string):
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(datetime_string,"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
        except ValueError:
            return False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
parsed = datetime.datetime.strptime("2/26/2009 3:00 PM", r'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
iso_formatted = parsed.isoformat()
print(iso_formatted)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [locale module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) combined with `time.strptime()` to ensure the date/time is in the proper order (month, day, year, etc). Or, you could do simple regex...

`pattern = re.compile(r'\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2} (AM|PM)')`
...I am not a regex pro lol, there's probably a better pattern.

You can also use the `datetime` module and create a new datetime object with the locale constant and have it convert the numbers to their proper type (day, month, year).

Good luck!